# How to carry on with a if statement in a new function?

Tags: c

So, I'm making a program in C and want to make a new function, but only if the if-statement is true, so if the if-statement is true, it will carry on to the next function and if not it will end.

Here is my if-statement

```
void UserNameInput ()
{
    printf("Please Login\n");
    printf("Username: ");
    scanf("%29s",UsersInput); // add 29 (maximum length to read) to avoid buffer overrun.Buffer Overflow
    //printf("You Entered %s", UsersInput); This says what you printed
    if (strcmp(UsersInput, RealUsername) == 0)
    {
        printf("Logged in");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Wrong Username");
    }
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [ask] page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: You are not *making* a new function at runtime, you are *calling* (or not!) some *existing* function (in your code `printf`) and you can *define* your own functions and you might call them conditionally.

Comment: DO NOT TAKE OFF PLEASE

Comment: ***NO.*** Leave your question as-is and accept an answer or delete your question if possible. Do not modify your question like that! Please **roll back to the previous version**.

Comment: You can always post your fix as an answer.EDIT :As an aside people should comment first before downvoting,it just discourages newbies.

Comment: Not really related, but please be aware that hardcoding credentials into your (client) executable and comparing that to user input offers zero security as anyone can easily patch your binary and remove the `if` statement, so to speak (make it always/never execute).

Answer (score 1):

The `return` keyword literally *returns* from a function, optionally returning a *return value*.

If some condition evaluates as true, you can `return` from the function then.
If not, just proceed and call the next function.

Besides, there are other execution flow control statements such as `goto`, `break`, and `continue`.